# From array of objects, extract value at certain index --> undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have a problem in getting a value from a certain index form an array of objects.

The Array looks something like that:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

When I open them in the Crome console, it looks like this:

[image]

The thing is that I want the value of `uuid` from one of this Objects.

If I write `console.log(this.myArray[0].uuid)` I am getting the uuid from index 0.

But as soon as I write `console.log(this.myArray[index].uuid)`, where index is a number, I only get `undefined`.

I already tried

```
var test = _.map(this.myArray,"uuid");
console.log(test[index].uuid)
```

but that only get's me `undefined`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I thin you want `test[index]`, after the map. The map method is returning the `uuid` property into the new array; you're treating it as though it's turning objects, each having a `uuid` property.

Comment: I just tried
`var test = _.map(test[index](this.mycards,"uuid"));`
`console.log(test);`
But I only get `swipeToRate.controller.js:189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined(…)`

Comment: That's because `test[index](this.mycards,"uuid")` treats `test[index]` as a function, attempting to pass `this.mycards` and `"uuid"` as arguments. Well, actually that's another problem; this seems to be complaining that `test` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want index loop array like this

```
for(var i = 0;i<this.myArray.length;i++){

console.log(this.myArray[i].uuid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken on how `_.map` works when passing a *key*:

```
let arr = [
  { index: 4, name: 'Hello' },
  { index: 9, name: 'World' }
]

_.map(arr, 'index') // produces [4, 9]
```

As a result, if you wish to access the *index* value, you would do so directly from the array itself.

```
let indexes = _.map(arr, 'index')

indexes[0] // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already tried

```
var test = _.map(this.mycards,"uuid");
console.log(test);
console.log(test[index]);
```

the fist console.log

```
console.log(test);
```

results in an Array with all the uuid's:

```
["3c539a73-d569-4512-b558-291164f34529", "b6920edc-77a8-4ac6-8fa3-65c7b05ea556", "9d8afb0c-5268-44a1-b02f-0772357025d0", "4a33b232-7c1d-4ee7-b53c-3615c0fbd7d3", "68888839-a888-4595-9be9-3ec07fe35850", "0ab242ca-e6e1-4497-871e-196c3a05e0ec", "0c311bc6-c396-45a9-865e-19cdc8800bf7", "3add00ad-7371-417a-89ae-e4f0966ab503", "ac503849-5476-4710-9c2e-a514a178c4f5"]
```

but with `console.log(test[index]);` I get again `undefined` as a result.

The thing is, that my method looks something like that:

```
event(index, eventObject) {
...  
};
```

and `index` is always a number, which I don't know, because it differs every time the method is called.

But for some reason when I put in a number instead of `index` (which is also a number) like this `this.myArray[0].uuid` I get the a result. 
But when I change to `this.myArray[index].uuid` I get undefined.

I even tried `parseInt(index)` but that also didn't work.